# How to assign a predicate to extra-validator-fn?

Tags: validation, clojure, schema, plumatic-schema

How would I assign a predicate to each check in the extra-validator-fn of the following schema defrecord:

```
(s/defrecord Item
         [type :- (s/enum :solid :liquid)
          unit :- (s/enum :kg :ml)]
         (s/fn [{:as this :keys [type unit]}]
               (or (and (= type :solid) (= unit :kg))
                   (and (= type :liquid) (= unit :ml)))))
```

The extra validation throws an exception in this example:

`(s/validate Item (map->Item {:type :solid :unit :ml}))`

Here it reads: `(not (passes-extra-validation? a-apriori.cli.core.Item))`

However, I would like it to read: `(not ('invalid-unit-for-type a-apriori.cli.core.Item))`